# Tratamiento de missings y maquetado final de r a excel

Tags: r

Tengo un problema a la hora de tratar con los missings en R y luego sacar un fichero Excel sin los missings, aquí estan los datos que quiero manipular

```
col1=c("Sujeto1","Sujeto2","Sujeto3","Sujeto4","Sujeto5","Sujeto6")
col2=c("A",NA,NA,"G",NA,NA)
col3=c(NA,NA,NA,"K","H","Z")
col4=c(NA,"P",NA,NA,NA,"Q")
col5=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
col6=c(NA,NA,NA,"B","C",NA)
col7=c("E",NA,NA,"D",NA,"Y")

data=data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7)



> data
 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
1 Sujeto1    A <NA> <NA>   NA <NA>    E
2 Sujeto2 <NA> <NA>    P   NA <NA> <NA>
3 Sujeto3 <NA> <NA> <NA>   NA <NA> <NA>
4 Sujeto4    G    K <NA>   NA    B    D
5 Sujeto5 <NA>    H <NA>   NA    C <NA>
6 Sujeto6 <NA>    Z    Q   NA <NA>    Y
```

Y quiero que el output sea un Excel que quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar no estan los missings y cada individuo tiene un numero diferente de columnas. Para hacer el output en Excel se tiene que utilizar el siguiente comando:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx2(x=data,file="Data.xlsx",row.names = F)
```

Es la primera vez que pregunto por aquí, me he leído el manual y diría que no incumplo ningun requisito ya que en principio no parece que se necesite mucho código para hacer la transformación que pido y me parece suficientemente concreto lo que pido. De no ser así pido disculpas de antemano por las molestias ocasionadas y editaré lo que haga falta para que quede en un formato adecuado para este foro.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda, de verdad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por ser la primera vez que preguntas, dejame decirte que los has hecho más que bien. La pregunta es clara y concisa, agregas un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible,  una muestra de lo que estarías esperando, lo que estamos del otro lado no podemos pedir nada más. Ahora con respecto a tu consulta, lo que podrías hacer es un alineado de las columnas con valores hacia la izquierda haciendo que los `NA` se muevan a la derecha.

Partimos de tu `data.frame` original:

```
data    

     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
1 Sujeto1    A <NA> <NA>   NA <NA>    E
2 Sujeto2 <NA> <NA>    P   NA <NA> <NA>
3 Sujeto3 <NA> <NA> <NA>   NA <NA> <NA>
4 Sujeto4    G    K <NA>   NA    B    D
5 Sujeto5 <NA>    H <NA>   NA    C <NA>
6 Sujeto6 <NA>    Z    Q   NA <NA>    Y
```

Y haciendo uso de la funcionalidad base, podríamos hacer esto:

```
data[-1] <- t(apply(data[,-1],MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x) {c(x[!is.na(x)],x[is.na(x)])}))
```

El resultado:

```
data

     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
1 Sujeto1    A    E <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 Sujeto2    P <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 Sujeto3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4 Sujeto4    G    K    B    D <NA> <NA>
5 Sujeto5    H    C <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
6 Sujeto6    Z    Q    Y <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Ahora simplemente salvar en el Excel tal como lo estabas haciendo.

Explicación:

- Con `data[,-1]` definimos que solo trabajaremos con todas las columnas menos la primera
- Con [`apply()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) y usando `MARGIN=1` aplicamos sobre cada fila del `data.farme` anterior una función `c(x[!is.na(x)],x[is.na(x)])` que devuelve un vector cuyos primeros valores son los que no son `NA` y luego los `NA`
- Como el resultado final se acomoda por columna hacemos un transpose con [`t()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html) para respetar la orientación original
- Por último solo modificamos los valores requeridos aplicando el cambio solo a `data[,-1]`

Una forma un poco más compacta y que me gusta un poco más, podría ser:

```
data[-1] <- t(apply(data[,-1],MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x) {x[order(is.na(x))]}))
```

En este caso el truco es ordenar las celdas de cada fila en función a si es `NA` o no: `x[order(is.na(x))]`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Patricio! Vaya pedazo de respuesta te has currado! No podria estar más agradecido, esta todo explicado de 10!